# Application Force Closes On Startup

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, forceclose

Well, I am trying to make an app that communicates with a socket I have set up, tested, and made work in the background of a simple java application.

The problem is, my app keeps force closing right away. You don't get a chance to see anything before it fcs.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LogMeInClientActivity extends Activity {
    private Socket s;
    private InetAddress hostIp, localIp;
    private final String hostName = "localhost";
    private final int port = 4000;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private final EditText usernameField = (EditText)     findViewById(R.id.username_field),
            passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
    private String username, password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("A");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("B");
        try {
            hostIp = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
            localIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Local Ip: " + localIp.toString());
            System.out.println("Host Ip: " + hostIp.toString());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            s = new Socket(hostIp, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class SignInButtonListener implements OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View clickedButton) {
            switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in:
                username = usernameField.getText().toString();
                password = passwordField.getText().toString();
                if (username.length() != 0 && password.length() != 0) {
                    out.println(username);
                    out.println(password);
                }
                out.flush();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, neither "A" or "B" prints out. The application simply fc's.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chriswins2much.Util"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LogMeInClientActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I used the above permission, because I heard it would help for it.

I updated the code to fix for the EditText NullPointerException fix (Only changed parts):

```
private EditText usernameField, passwordField;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("A");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        System.out.println("B");
        try {
                    // It's saying one of the errors are on line 37 (directly below)
            hostIp = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
            localIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Local Ip: " + localIp.toString());
            System.out.println("Host Ip: " + hostIp.toString());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            s = new Socket(hostIp, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

New logcat below:

```
04-19 02:46:56.292: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:57.049: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:46:57.103: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:57.450: E/dalvikvm(1289): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
04-19 02:46:57.462: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:57.669: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:46:58.069: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:58.409: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:46:58.650: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:58.779: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:46:59.009: I/System.out(1289): A
04-19 02:46:59.153: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:59.321: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:46:59.639: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:46:59.879: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:00.249: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:00.490: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:00.819: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:00.970: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:01.279: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:01.477: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:01.791: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:01.919: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:02.302: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:02.443: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:02.811: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:02.999: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:03.409: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:03.583: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:03.870: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:04.029: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:04.410: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:04.529: I/System.out(1289): B
04-19 02:47:04.603: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:04.850: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:05.020: D/AndroidRuntime(1289): Shutting down VM
04-19 02:47:05.020: W/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-19 02:47:05.101: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:05.460: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chriswins2much.Util/com.chriswins2much.Util.LogMeInClientActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:295)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at com.chriswins2much.Util.LogMeInClientActivity.onCreate(LogMeInClientActivity.java:37)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-19 02:47:05.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1289):     ... 11 more
04-19 02:47:05.779: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-19 02:47:06.839: I/dalvikvm(1289): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-19 02:47:07.000: I/dalvikvm(1289): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

!
Note: Here is a new, new updated code. Force closes are fixed!!! Thank you idiottiger!
There is still a problem though. It's not connecting to the port I have set up on localhost:4000 in java. I've tried it non-Android and it works fine. Here is my code to fix the Force close:

```
public void onCreate(View v){
    // Code...
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                try {
                    hostIp = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
                    localIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    System.out.println("Local Ip: " + localIp.toString());
                    System.out.println("Host Ip: " + hostIp.toString());
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    s = new Socket(hostIp, port);
                    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                    in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();


}
```

New logcat below (the latter half of it):

```
04-19 03:38:02.920: I/System.out(1490): Local Ip: localhost/127.0.0.1
04-19 03:38:03.099: I/System.out(1490): Host Ip: localhost/127.0.0.1
04-19 03:38:05.420: W/System.err(1490): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 4000): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
04-19 03:38:05.711: W/System.err(1490):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
04-19 03:38:05.711: W/System.err(1490):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-19 03:38:05.781: W/System.err(1490):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
04-19 03:38:05.781: W/System.err(1490):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
04-19 03:38:05.803: W/System.err(1490):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
04-19 03:38:05.809: W/System.err(1490):     at com.chriswins2much.Util.LogMeInClientActivity$1.run(LogMeInClientActivity.java:48)
04-19 03:38:05.839: W/System.err(1490):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-19 03:38:05.859: W/System.err(1490): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
04-19 03:38:05.925: W/System.err(1490):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
04-19 03:38:05.939: W/System.err(1490):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
04-19 03:38:05.979: W/System.err(1490):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-19 03:38:05.979: W/System.err(1490):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-19 03:38:05.989: W/System.err(1490):     ... 6 more
04-19 03:38:06.692: D/gralloc_goldfish(1490): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: This line is causing the error:     
passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);   Learn how to read the stack trace, it will tell you this (i.e., "Caused by:")

Comment: It's still not working, but yeah, I didn't see that before. Thanks in advance for future problems it might save me.

Comment: Are working on tablet application NetworkOnMainThread Exception will occur.Try to call from the another than ui thread area.Try to visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception and add Strict Mode in your code.

Comment: For the Strict Mode read out this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html. This mode is useful when you have to start your thread over ui thread.

Comment: Like this? StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build());

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK... Apparently it was the 'localhost' thing. Android runs on another subnet and reserves 127.0.0.1 for itself, so when I tried to connect to the server I set up on localhost:4000, I was calling Android's reserved localhost ip of 127.0.0.1, while the computer's localhost  ip was changed to 10.0.2.2 on port 4000.

The fix implemented? It's simple:

I changed this

```
private final String hostName = "localhost";
```

to this

```
private final String hostName = "10.0.2.2";
```

Or if I had tried it to my ip address (not the localhost one), then it should have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

these code may be have some problem:

```
 private final EditText usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_field),
            passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
```

the view need init after `setContentView`, so change to this:

```
private EditText usernameField,passwordField;
```

add follow code after `setContentView`:

```
usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_field),
passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_field);
```

if it can't fix your problem, you need check the view id: `R.id.username_field` and `R.id.password_field` existed in your `main.xml` file or not.

update:

you new error: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged. See the document Designing for Responsiveness.

it like you `InetAddress.getByName` need block the `main thread`, so try to use in another thread, or change the sdk target version to low like: < 11 (android 3.0)

also , you need add the network permission in your xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: can you update using new code and paste the new error message?

Comment: `It's not connecting to the port I have set up on localhost:4000 in java. I've tried it non-Android and it works fine. ` how do you test? the question is: the server with port 4000 in your android device or not? and the `SocketSever` is started ? and if not the socket, you need connect with urlconnection.

Comment: I have a ServerSocket set up on port 4000 in Java, which is set up on the same computer as the emulator. Right now, it simply creates a new, custom Thread that reads input and echos it. I've set up a Socket, set up on localhost, port 4000, in another java program that simply takes input from the keyboard, using a Scanner(System. In) object and sends it. I am using both of them in eclipse's console.. They send and echo to each other fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using something related to internet. and i didnt see permission for that in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I added it to the manifest, but it's still giving me the same exact logcat thingy. I mean exactly the same.

Comment: I think it's that line 37 thing, but I'm not sure

Comment: oh sorry. its permission not permissions

Comment: hostIp = InetAddress.getByName(hostName); wheras hostName = "localhost"?

Comment: di you paste it from here? if so, change it to permission. not permissions

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />          -- right?

Comment: It's still not working. It's still giving that line 37 thing in the logcat error message

Answer (score 0):

your question is AndroidManifest.xml

if you change your
     **uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" to uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"**
the program is ok.

i don't know way